# Why would installation method affect .NET service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, multicast, advanced-installer

I have built a WCF service that is hosted in a Windows Service following this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx.  Part of what the code in the service does is join a multicast group and listen for data that is broadcast to the group.  Then it processes it. I have found that when I install the service manually using InstallUtil it works fine.  To install it manually I do the following:

- Build the MyService project in Visual Studio.
- Right click on the Visual Studio Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator
- Navigate to the folder that has the MyService.exe file
- Run the InstallUtil command as follows: installutil.exe MyService.exe

The service installs in Windows fine and then I start it.  Then I run my ASP.NET application which is the client for the service and it runs fine. The service receives and processes the data just fine.

However I am trying to use [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) to build an MSI or EXE that will install the service and the ASP.NET application all at once so it doesn't have to be done manually.  I am able to successfully create the Advanced Installer project that does this and it actually installs both the ASP.NET application and the Windows Service just fine and it starts my Windows Service too.  However the really strange thing is that when I run the application I find that my service code can not receive any multicast data.  It seems to block on that line of code and I never get any data.  Does anyone know why this would happen?  I have tried using an EXE and using "Run As Administrator" when I do the Advanced Installer installation.  Here is the code from my service.

```
_groupAddress = IPAddress.Parse(_myIPAddress);
_listener = new UdpClient(_myPort);
_groupEP = new IPEndPoint(_groupAddress, _myPort);

_listener.JoinMulticastGroup(_groupAddress);
byte[] _bytes = _listener.Receive(ref _groupEP);
```

It seems to block on that last line of code and it never receives any data.  This only happens when I install using Advanced Installer.  When I install manually it works fine.

Comment: Different subnet? Trying to jump over a router? Both these will prevent UDP multicast from working. You will need something like IGMP proxy on the router in that case.

Answer (score 0):

A service is configured to run under the identity of a user. Is this different when you install with the different methods?

Do you use the same port number in both cases, if not it could be the firewall.

99% sure that you have checked it, but check that the service is running after it is installed using advanced installer.

Check the event log for problems with the service.

Comment: With both installation methods it uses the same account (LocalSystem) and the same port.  I wondered also if somehow the port was being blocked in one situation.  But I can't imagine how an installation method would block a port.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your Windows Service is not running with sufficient credentials to perform this action.  To test this, I'd recommend trying to change the user account being used for the service to see if that makes any difference.

To do this, go to the services applet (start, run, type *services.msc*).  Find your service, right-click, properties, "Log On" tab, choose "This Account" and select an administrator user account that the service can run under.

Comment: Yeah, that's the strange thing.  With both installation methods it uses the LocalSystem account.  So I can't see any difference there.

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought as the guys said this was a problem with the user credentials. But since you said in both cases the service is installed under the LocalSystem the problem seems to be elsewhere.

I recommend you first check the system "Events Viewer" for any messages regarding your message failing to start, maybe there you can find more information about the failure case.

If you can't find more detailed there I suggest a little bit of reverse engineering, to see what InstallUtil does and Advanced Installer doesn't, or the other way around. Advanced Installer comes along with the [Repackager tool](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-repackager.html). You can use this tool to capture the system changes performed when running "InstallUtil" by providing a dummy executable to the Repackager when it is asking for the setup package, for example Notepad.

When the Repackager launches Notepad, leave it open and run your install command for the service, after the service finished installing, close Notepad and leave the repackager do its job. Then analyze the new project that it generates to see what resources has captured, like files, registry, services, etc...

You can also capture the install package create by Advanced Installer to see if the services installation from it creates less or more registration info for your service.